# Hibernate column used as a part of a composite primary key and a part composite foreign key at the same time

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I got this table structure where we are not allowed to change and i have problems finding an Hibernate mapping solution.

Table A

```
a1 (pk)
a2
```

---

Table B

```
b1 (pk, fk on 'A.a1')
b2 (pk)
b3
```

---

Table C

```
c1 (pk, fk on 'B.b1')
c2 (pk, fk on 'B.b2')
c3 (pk)
c4
```

---

Table D

```
d1 (pk)
d2 (pk, fk on 'A.a1')
d3 (fk on 'C.c2')
d4 (fk on 'C.c3')
d5
```

---

Now the problem i got is on theb level of **column d2** of Table D which is a part of composite key and also a part of foreign key on Table C

In Hibernate I did this

```
@Embeddable
public class TableDId {
    private Long d1;
    private TableA d2;

    @Column(name="d1")
    public Long getD1() {
        return this.d1;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="d2")
    public Long getD2() {
        return this.d2;
    }
    // Setters
}


@Entity
public class TableD {
    private TableDId id;
    private TableC tableC;

    @EmbeddedId @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)    
    public TableDId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="id.d2", referencedColumnName="c1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="d3", referencedColumnName="c2"),
        @JoinColumn(name="d4", referencedColumnName="c3")
    })
    public TableC getTableC() {
        return tableC;
    }

    // Setters
}
```

As you can guess that doesn't work, i got an Hibernate error when saving a new TableD

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Unknown column 'id.d2' in 'field list'
```

Can anyone propose a working solution?

Thanx a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should post all annotated classes. Are you using in all classes *@EmbeddedId* or do you also use *IdClass*? 
You should have a look at the JPA 2 specification in the "Mapping of Derived Identities" section. I reckon you need to use *@MapsId* on the association. Or place the *@Id* annotation on the association as well, but this will depend on how exactly you mapped the other classes.

Comment: this doesn't provide a solution at all

Answer (score 1):

```
@JoinColumn(name="id.d2", referencedColumnName="c1")
```

Try to remove id. from mapping

```
@JoinColumn(name="d2", referencedColumnName="c1")
```

Example http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html (section 2.2.6)

Comment: That doesn't work too; `Repeated column in mapping for entity: TableD column: d2 (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")` and  adding `insert="false" update="false"` doesn't get it to work either